# Delete end of line starting at second occurence of search pattern in vim

Tags: search, vim, replace

I have a text file in which many lines contain twice the symbol =, as in:

```
Animals:
clown=fish=vertebrate
cow=mammal=vertebrate
bug=insect=invertebrate
slug==snail
etc
```

I want to delete everything that is after the second = on each line only if the two = are not together, resulting in:

```
Animals:
clown=fish
cow=mammal
bug=insect
slug==snail
etc
```

How I can I do this?
I guess search for the second occurence of =, then select all results, then select until the end of line, then delete, but most of these steps I couldn't find a easy way to do.

Comment: What did you try? We prefer "I did this but it doesn't work, how can I fix it?" to "How can I do this?" questions.

Comment: I looked how to select all occurences of a search pattern, but found nothing (I only found how to highlight them)

Comment: I have used /=\(.\+\)= to look for double = with something in between, but that selects both =, not only the second one.

Comment: I think x should be enough to delete once everything is selected...

Comment: And I think $ in visual block should select until the end of line, but I do not know how to enter this mode from all the search results at once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
%s/=[^=]\+\zs=.*//
```

The interesting part is `\zs`. Look for it in the docs via `:help \zs`.

Beside that, I'm matching an equal sign (the first `=`) followed by 1 or more (`\+`) characters other than the equal sign (`[^=]`), followed by another equal sign.

Answer (score 2):

Press `:` to go to command mode, then run this:

```
%s/\(\w\+=\w\+\).*/\1/g
```

Explanation: in entire file (`%`) substitute line with result from `\w\+=\w\+` search pattern (one equals sign, surrounded by non-zero-length words-characters.

Since this will only match on lines where the first `=` is surrounded by word-characters, it won't apply to lines like `slug==snail`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `:normal`

```
:%norm f=lf=D
```

This uses `f` to find the `=` character move to left, then search for another `=` using `f` before deleting with `D`. If an error occurs then that line is skipped